# How to do a reverse search in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am trying to do a search and replace on a string, doing a backward search on the pattern in shell script.

I have tried with the below, but it is not working for me

```
sed -r 's/ $/,/'
```

I am trying to apply this search and replace on a file having content like below

```
0 1 2 Comp level
```

I want the third space to be replaced with a comma

output should be like

```
0 1 2,Comp level
```

Comment: "doing a *backward* search" - why? how would that help?

Comment: why backwards? a simpleish regex could handle this quite easily

Comment: Reason i am doing a backward search is in the file that i have [which would be dynamically generated in script] i am sure that i need a comma in the third last pattern, but while doing a forward search i am not sure how many patterns i need to skip

Comment: Update your question then. Currently it says: "I want the third space to be replaced with a comma"

Comment: Try `sed 's/^\(.\+\)\s\([^\s]\+\)\s\([^\s]\+\)$/\1,\2 \3/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace third space by `,`:

```
 echo '0 1 2 Comp level' | sed 's/ /,/3'
```

Output:

```
0 1 2,Comp level
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a flag for this.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus, but its a forward search that is applied here, my data could be like 0 1 2,Comp level or it could also be 0 1 2 3 4,Comp level, so the flag which says the number of skip to be applied on pattern will be dynamic if i do a forward search

Comment: @BlessonMathew: Try this: `echo '0 1 2 Comp level' | rev | sed 's/ /,/2' | rev` or `echo '0 1 2 Comp level' | sed -E 's/ ([^0-9])/,\1/'`

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (click the hollow check mark symbol so it turns solid green) so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: @Cyrus I think your comment solution is basically what he's looking for, except I think you meant `echo '0 1 2 Comp level' | rev | sed 's/ /,/3' | rev`. It would probably be better if you update your answer.